# Command Prompt cannot find or run my Java File

Tags: java, cmd, javac

New programmer here, in terms of actually using an editor and running it. I have created a simple program that states this.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

I have already set the path to **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\"**.(current version"`1.8.0_151`"). In the cmd input, "java" and "javac" work until I attempt to find a file name either "HelloWorld.java" or "HelloWorld". How do I get cmd to find and run my java file? Thank you!

Comment: are you with your prompt on the folder your .java file is in? did you declare a package?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're not in the directory containing the java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to try it:

Open `C:\Temp` (or create if not exists)

Create new file called `HelloWorld.java`

Open `cmd`

Type `cd /d C:\Temp`

Type `javac HelloWorld.java`

Type `java HelloWorld`

Answer (score 1):

I did the following steps with your code and it worked:

- Open a command prompt in the folder where your `HelloWorld.java` is saved
- Make sure the class name is the same as the file name.
- Check if you have added java executable/folder to your system path, you can try: `java -version` (this should print information about your installed java version)
- Compile your code: `javac HelloWorld.java`
- Now there should be a class file generated: `HelloWorld.class`
- Run you main class: `java HelloWorld`
- Note: Without the `.class` extenstion
- Note: use `dir` instead of `ls` on Windows to see the files in the current directory
- Note: Do you have a `package` name specified?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you compile with javac
eg:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

you run the compiled byte code using java. You need to place yourself in the directory containing the compiled bytecode
eg

```
C:\introcs\hello\>java HelloWorld
Hello, World
```